# Retrieve ESG scores from yahoo finance

Tags: python, finance, yahoo

I am trying to retrieve some ESG scores from yahoo finance. there are some companies that do not have any, so what I am trying to do is to get the ones I can and then skip the ones that do not have.

Below is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

list_csv = pd.read_csv("constituents_csv.csv")
list_csv.iloc[65,0] = "BRK-B"
list_csv.iloc[78,0] = "BF-B"

symbols = list_csv['Symbol'].values.flatten().tolist()

sus = {}
for i,sym in enumerate(symbols):
    try:
         sus[sym] = float(yf.Ticker(symbols[i]).sustainability.loc['totalEsg'])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Do you have a question? The one thing that I would point out in your code is that you should not use bare except handlers, especially ones that completely ignore the error.

Comment: Another thing is that your use of `enumerate` seems redundant. You could just use `for sym in symbols` and replace `symbols[i]` with `sym`.

Comment: thank you for your comments. my question is basically if I am doing it right. it takes a long time to process it, though there are 505 symbols

Comment: Other than the issues that I raised in earlier comments, it looks right to me. I would definitely add proper exception handling and logging because `except: pass` will hide a multitude of possible runtime errors that you will probably want to know about,

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!